# JAVAFX + MVC + loading mask

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx-2

[image]

I am trying to load  mask image on `onclick` event while validating the in MVC architecture. I am unable to set loading image but able set loading image after the validation , where mediator is returning the view.

can we return view from Action page?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one thing, in the controller load your mask and start rest of the flow in new thread.once u get the response for logging-in then call the respective method for further processing.meaning keep the following things together in new thread and run. then you will get the access to those and your load mask will be done .